# Split execution in TF model conditionally

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am making a tensorflow model in two parts/blocks. The input + body is just a couple of convolutions and whatnot. In my current model the convolutional block feeds into a fully connected block and that makes a decision.

What I want to try to do is create multiple fully connected blocks and use a layer(s) that processes the output of the convolutional block. The max output index would correspond to the index of a fully connected block. The convolutional block would feed it's output to the chosen decision maker then.

[image: Example of the network]

The idea kinda comes from multi-task deep neural networks (https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.11504) but with a more hands off approach to choosing what head to use.

The issue I have is this:

I need to conditionally change the execution of the model and I am not entirely sure how to do that. I am using Keras right now and trying to get this to work with Model's and Sequential's is sort of what is stumping me here. My primary experience with the API is using model.train(...) and it seems I might need to take a more manual approach to this maybe?

Thanks in advance! I am sort of new to neural networks so I am sorry if this is a silly question.

EDIT: Model decision is made by the block to the left. In this example I am saying it is a fully connected layer followed by a softmax activation.

- Input: Flattened output of the convolutions
- Output: The argmax of the final output of a fully connected layer. The argmax is going to be the index of one of the decision makers

In all reality I am planning to use other methods but for simplicity it is what I just described.

Comment: So who makes the model decision? Would be helpful if you can give more info how the "model decision" works (e.g. input/output)

Comment: @thushv89 Updated the question with what I meant. The input to the "decision maker" is the output of the convolutions. The output (in this example) would be the output of a fully connected layer with softmax activation. The argmax is an index of the "decision maker" to use. The decision maker's input is the raw output of the convolutions

Comment: Is it like, for one batch of data you have a single scalar index and not a batch of indices?

Comment: For now yes, one index for a batch. Later I want to toy around with it being able to change but for the meantime 1 index = 1 batch. Each batch will have a different index (and, as I stated in the question, each index corresponds to a different decision maker)

Comment: My solution will work both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated to do what you're trying to do. But nevertheless possible.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

height = 64
width = 64
n_channels = 3
n_layers = 4

# We have the simple convolutional output here
inp = layers.Input(shape=(height, width, n_channels))
conv_out = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same')(inp)
conv_out = layers.Flatten()(conv_out)

# (Model decision) Your model producing the correct ID of the fully connected layer (batch size, 4)
out = layers.Dense(n_layers, activation='softmax')(conv_out)

# This is the tricky bit. We are creating indices to gather the parameters from the corresponding layer
# Both best_out, range_out are (batch_size, 1) concatenated to (batch_size, 2)
# They would be like [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 0), .... (batch_size-1, 2)] type indices
best_out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.argmax(x, axis=-1), axis=-1))(out)
range_out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.cumsum(tf.ones_like(x), exclusive=True))(best_out)
gather_ids = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([range_out, best_out])

# Compute the output for all dense layers
final_outputs = [layers.Dense(10)(conv_out) for _ in range(n_layers)]
# Stack the outputs (batch size, n_layers, 10)
final_output = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack(x, axis=1))(final_outputs)
# Gather the outputs corresponding to correct indices (batch_size, 10)
final_out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather_nd(x[0], x[1]))([final_output, gather_ids])

model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[best_out, final_out])

model.summary()
```

Simple test

Let's see if we get the same vector for a given index, if we pass in an array of ones.

```
x0 = np.ones(shape=(3, height, width, n_channels))
x0[2,:,:,:] = np.random.normal(size=(height, width, n_channels))
y0 = model.predict(x0)

for ri in range(y0[0].size):
  print(y0[0][ri])
  print(y0[1][ri])
  print('\n')
```

Output (Batch of 3 elements)

```
Max index => [1]
[-0.3227892   1.1366667  -0.43643862  1.0002458  -1.2778764  -1.1994138
  0.18452626  0.89942855  0.33907077 -0.22196433]


Max index => [1]
[-0.3227892   1.1366667  -0.43643862  1.0002458  -1.2778764  -1.1994138
  0.18452626  0.89942855  0.33907077 -0.22196433]


Max index => [2]
[ 0.18891329  0.18289518  0.43710774 -0.2164327  -0.03203449  0.16306376
 -0.0089941   0.3098799  -1.0531532  -0.34144163]
```

Comment: Gonna try this tomorrow and give it a big ol' check if it works like I think it will. I was thinking about using Lambda's but my mind went straight to putting a model IN it and I was a bit concerned on that front (if that would even work). This is SO MUCH nicer and I am really looking forward to trying this. Thanks a ton in advance!